# Split array in exponentially sized sub arrays

Tags: arrays, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

Let **R** be an array with **N** elements. I'm looking for way to split **R** into **P** sub-arrays, whereby sub-array should exponentially decrease in its size. Also, it would be nice to have an additional parameter specifying how much it decreases each time (meaning, how steep a corresponding function curve would be).

A very simple example would be splitting R = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} into {0,1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7}, {8,9}, {10} for P=4. Or another steeper solution for P=3: {0,1,3,4,5,6,7}, {8,9}, {10}.

I was looking into doing that by means of the geometric distribution function. However, it's kind of hard to find a good estimate for p and it is also rather inflexible.